# 'Index' object is not callable in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. Can someone explain what happened when I try to get index information after reading the csv file?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', index_col=0, skiprows=1)

for col in df.columns:
    if col[:2]=='01':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='02':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='03':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:1]=='№':
        df.rename(columns={col:'#'+col[1:]}, inplace=True)

names_ids = df.index.str.split('\s\(') # split the index by '('

df.index = names_ids.str[0] 
df['ID'] = names_ids.str[1].str[:3] 

df = df.drop('Totals')
df.head()
```

Then I get this dataframe.

[image: dataframe]

But when I try to get the index information using df.index(), I got an error, saying Index object is not callable.

Comment: Try df.index instead

Comment: Why are you calling it as though it were a function?  It isn't, which you clearly know, because a few lines earlier is this line of code `df.index.str.split(...)`

Comment: Thanks. Those lines are given in the assignment, so actually I do not notice that. I am also new to python, so sorry for my stupid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use "df.index", "df.index()" suggests that it is a function. "df.index" simply means that "index" is a subset of the DataFrame. You can call columns the same way (e.g. df['ID'] --> df.ID).

Also, it is a good habit to specify the axis in "df.drop". It defaults to 0 (index), so you will get an error if you try to drop a column without addressing this (e.g. df = df.drop('some_column', 1))